# Get ID of Selected List Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the ID of a selected list item using JavaScript. Basically I am trying to get the ID using JavaScript and then in the same javascript redirect to a page with the selected ID in the querystring.

This is my javascript:

```
function GetID() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    window.location.href = "/_layouts/CustomApplicationPage/CustomApplicationPage.aspx?ID=" + items;
}
```

But the results I get in my querystring are:

```
CustomApplicationPage.aspx?ID=[object Object]
```

Does anyone know how to get the ID of the selected list item or point me to the correct method to use in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `items` is a `Dictionary` type as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409526(v=office.14).aspx

Since you are only trying to get a single value back, you can likely get what you need by referencing the first value in the `Dictionary`.

```
window.location.href = "/_layouts/CustomApplicationPage/CustomApplicationPage.aspx?ID=" + items[0].id;
```