# How to reference selected list items in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, list, sharepoint-2010

This is SP2010 + VS2010.

What I got so far: I have a list "myList". I have a custom Ribbon button working, done in VS2010, with a web part postback bound to it. On the list's AllItems.aspx page, I added in the web part, and there it is. The button interacts so that I click it and the web part does what it does when the button is clicked.

Looking at Elements.xml, the button's CommandAction, it is currently this:

```
CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('WebPartDelEventInstructorPostback','');"
```

**But back at the postback handler , I don't know how to reference the selected list items.** I looked, but could not find them, even using a breakpoint and combing through the Watch list.

If that's really vague, I apolgzie. I've spent days even getting this far and it's been a painful climb upon the jagged rocks of SP2010 and VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=203

To make it work, I changed

```
CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('WebPartDelEventInstructorPostback','');"
```

to

```
CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('WebPartDelEventInstructorPostback','{SelectedItemId}');"
```

and then over in my c# code,

```
string eventArgument = this.Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

gave me that value passed from {SelectedItemId}.

The caveat? So far it only works with only one checked item. If more than one is checked, the value passed is null.

Comment: So the answer on how to get the IDs when multiple items are checked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738605/sharepoint-2010-get-id-of-selected-list-item